# Magento 2.4.4 - Elasticsearch sku autocomplete stop after 3 symbols

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch 7.

**STEP #1** : we type the first 3 characters of a SKU in the search engine, we get many product suggestions

**STEP #2** :we type 4 characters of a SKU in the search engine it says "Sorry, nothing has been found for ...

In our test, we only use SKUs related to online products, products that Elasticsearch was suggesting in step #1

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: move to Smile ElasticSuite it will solve all your search issues. https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite